# Htaccess : https for all except specific domains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following rules to redirect all request to `https://www.mainsite.com`

```
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now I want to redirect `http://another-domain.com` to a specific folder (blog) but without `https` so I added this. but

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?another-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?another-domain$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog/index.php [L]
```

Even with that `http://another-domain.com` is still redirected to `https://www.mainsite.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!(www\.)?another-domain\.com$)(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?another-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).+)$ blog/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?another-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ blog/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I still get a redirection to `https`.

Comment: It's work now a co-worker made an error on the`index.php` , thank you.